# Running springdoc-openapi on a non-root path

Tags: java, spring-boot, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I'm trying to run springdoc-openapi 1.6.14 with a spring boot app that runs on non root path (in this exaple /bla).
Everything works fine in my local dev environment, which runs on a root path.
I have tried the following configurations:

If I have no conf:
UI makes request to
https://myapp.com/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
Doesn't work. 404 is returned and so UI doesn't work.

However when testing manually, the following works:
https://myapp.com/bla/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
And returns data with 'url' property, but it's not related to the app path so wouldn't work anyway:

```
{"configUrl":"/v3/api-docs/swagger-config","oauth2RedirectUrl":"http://10.11.12.13:8080/swagger-ui/oauth2-redirect.html","url":"/v3/api-docs","validatorUrl":""}
```

If I have conf:

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    configUrl: /bla/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
```

UI makes request to
https://myapp.com/bla/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
request to swagger-config works, but doesn't return correct answer - it's missing 'url' property:

```
{
    "configUrl": "/bla/v3/api-docs/swagger-config",
    "oauth2RedirectUrl": "http://10.11.12.13:8080/swagger-ui/oauth2-redirect.html",
    "validatorUrl": ""
}
```

As a result default petstore is open

If I have conf:

```
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    path: /bla/v3/api-docs
```

UI makes request to
https://myapp.com/bla/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
Doesn't work. 404 is returned and so UI doesn't work.

However when testing manually, the following works:
https://myapp.com/bla/bla/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
and returns the correct data:

```
{"configUrl":"/bla/v3/api-docs/swagger-config","oauth2RedirectUrl":"http://10.11.12.13:8080/swagger-ui/oauth2-redirect.html","url":"/bla/v3/api-docs","validatorUrl":""}
```

If I have conf that includes both previous:

```
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    path: /bla/v3/api-docs
  swagger-ui:
    configUrl: /bla/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
```

UI makes request to
https://myapp.com/bla/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
Doesn't work. 404 is returned and so UI doesn't work.

Once again, when testing manually, the following works:
https://myapp.com/bla/bla/v3/api-docs/swagger-config

However when testing manually, the following works:
https://myapp.com/bla/bla/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
but this time doesn't return correct data, missing 'url' property:

```
{"configUrl":"/bla/v3/api-docs/swagger-config","oauth2RedirectUrl":"http://10.11.12.13:8080/swagger-ui/oauth2-redirect.html","validatorUrl":""}
```

So can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? How am I supposed to run it on a non-root path?

Comment: I used face the same issue. What worked for me is adding `server.servlet.context-path=/my/custom/path` in `application.properties` file, and removing @RequestMapping in the controller classes, if any.